Why do I get doubles quotes issue while using PostgreSQL Anonymizer?
While using postgresql_anonymizer:
Step 1. SECURITY LABEL FOR anon ON COLUMN "Users"."Email" IS 'MASKED WITH FUNCTION anon.fake_email()';
Step 2. SELECT anon.anonymize_database();
Аfter running the step 2 query I get an error of escape double quotes.
ERROR: syntax error at or near "Email"
LINE 1: UPDATE public. "Users" SET "\"Email\"" = CAST (anon.fake_email...
                                      ^

QUERY: UPDATE public. "Users" SET "\"Email\"" = CAST (anon.fake_email() AS text)
CONTEXT: SQL function "anonymize_database" statement 1

I've:

Ubuntu 22.04
PostgreSQL 15.10
postgresql_anonymizer_15


Why don't you ask the people who maintain the anonymizer?

@LaurenzAlbe: Is there some kind of popularity threshold for asking Stack Overflow? It’s true that this is probably something to contact them over, but only because the answer is that it’s a bug that has to be reported and fixed.

Step one: Never use UPPER case in your SQL objects like column names. Doing so avoids the need for double quotes and this might solve your issue. But that depends on the code and I don't have access to this code.

@Ry- I think it is perfectly fine to ask the question here (I didn't vote to close). I just thought that asking the authors may have a better chance of reaching somebody who knows the answer.

@Ry, I faced an issue,
I dont know its a bug or I'm following wrong syntax or steps, so I asked here.

@FrankHeikens
Ok,
But,
I have an old database where I can't change the column names, but I still need to use PostgreSQL Anonymizer.
